# Jackson XML serialization does not produce desired result

Tags: java, xml, kotlin, jackson

The goal is to create a class to serialize to the following xml:

```
<ParticipantID code="AA">participant name</PArticipantID>
```

I would expect the following class to work (code shown in kotlin):

```
data class ParticipantID(
    @JacksonXmlProperty(isAttribute = true)
    var code:String,

    @JacksonXmlText
    var value:String
```

)

yet serializing produces

```
<ParticipantID> <code>AA</code> participant name</PArticipantID>
```

Answer (score 0):

It turns out that it is possible to make this work using the following class:

```
class ParticipantID(code:String, value:String) {

@JacksonXmlProperty(isAttribute = true)
private var code:String = code
    get() = field

@JacksonXmlText
private var value:String = value
    get() = field
```

}